# How to login to whatsapp after I use my whatsapp number as whatsapp business Number?

Tags: whatsapp, twilio-api

I would like to send a WhatsApp message from my project. So I use twilio WhatsApp API and I use my own phone number as the sender and link whatsApp Business Account with my Twilio Account. To use my own whatsapp number as business number, I delete my account from whatsapp messenger and use it as business number since error is shown as the image.Please see this link to see image [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RuRD.png). Everything including sending message from project is ok, but one thing is I can't login to my own number using whatsapp messenger or whatsapp business app. When I try to login to whatsapp messenger or business app, the error show "WhatsApp is temporarily unavailable. Please try again in 1 hour".

My question is

- I think I need to login to whatsapp business app only since my phone no is registered as business account. is my assumption true?
- which step do I need to follow to login to whatsapp?

Please help me. Thanks all in advance.

For reference, I follow along the instructions just like the below link.
[text](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up)

If I can't login, how can I manually reply to my customers?

Comment: What do you mean with "I delete my account from whatsapp". Do you mean you already had a Twilio number enabled for WhatsApp or are you talking about your personal phone number?

Comment: I am talking my personal phone number. is my question a little complicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a phone number is registered with WhatsApp Business Manager (API), you can not use it in WhatsApp Business App concurrently, and wise versa.

Read the note in [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started/migrate-existing-whatsapp-number-to-a-business-account):

> *Once you migrate a phone number to the WhatsApp Business Platform, you cannot use that number on the WhatsApp Business App concurrently. Your number must be used either on the Business Platform or on the Business App.*

---

> If I can't login, how can I manually reply to my customers?

I am not sure about [twilio-api](/questions/tagged/twilio-api), maybe they provide a chat conversation dashboard,

If they do not then you have to develop your own dashboard using webhook notifications, to communicate with the users.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will check whether they provide a chat conversation dashboard in twilio api.

Comment: Then is there a way or method to send WhatsApp message without needing to migrate to Whatsapp messenger account to WhatsApp Business Platform?

Comment: No there is no way in WhatsApp Business cloud API.

Comment: I editted the answer wrt the Twilio platform and it's pending approval. The short answer is: The Twilio WA API is only available to phone numbers purchased on the platform.